# How to add UITableView section using interface builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a storyboard with UITableViewController subclass in it. It looks like this:

[image: UITableView sections in interface builder]

I inherited this project, so I didn't make the section inside table view by myself. I can't find a way to add table view section (blue box on the image) other than copy/pasting the existing one and modifying later.

The object library doesn't seem tho have this component.

I know that I can manipulate sections in code, but my question is can this section (blue box on the image) be added using IB only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply select your `UITableView` in the document outline and increment the sections like so:

[image: Storyboard picture]

Answer (score 5):

For static tables, you can click on tableview in view hierarchy and then from property inspector you can mention number of sections for tableview. As shown in image.

[image]